# How do I send email solely through ASP.NET and Exchange server 2013?

Tags: asp.net, email

I am creating a contact page for my website, and have setup Exchange Server 2013 on my server, running Windows Server 2008R2. I have the HTML done, and this was working just using SMTP until I installed Exchange server. So, I now am coming here to ask you for your help in using EWS straight from ASP.NET.

Any help you would be able to give would be much appreciated. Thank you.

~LP

Comment: You'll have to be a little more explicit; exactly what error are you getting and can you show the code you're using?

Comment: Why not continue to use SMTP if you've already done the work for it?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it just isn't sending the mail. The code that I used for SMTP is this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cd06ab55d04e8323d549dd35bf2b47ed

However, the mail is not being "picked up". so, I want to switch to EWS, and have tried a few things to no avail.